# What should be the Mail server (SMTP) port while setting up the Progress OpenEdge Management?

Tags: smtp, openedge, progress-4gl, mail-server

I am trying to set up Progress OpenEdge Management set up. For that, I typed https://localhost:9090 in my browser. Then after login with default first-time password, it prompts for changing the password and also asked for setting up the SMTP host and port details. I have tried some port numbers like 25, 2525, 465, 587. But these are not working for me. Everytime error is showing like:

> Configuration Errors
>       You must specify a value for the local trend database port.

Can anyone suggest me how to get this Mail server (SMTP) port number.

Screenshot attached for reference: [image: MailServer(SMTP)PortDetail]

Answer (score 1):

Error is about local trend database port and not SMTP port. Provide a valid port number (free port) for field "Trend database port" and you should be all set.